# How do I expose variables from a uasset?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I want to access some variables from a uasset in order to animate them (variables from the gerstner wave object from the official water ocean plugin). I know that in order to animate them they need to be exposed, which can be done in blueprint and likely also in c++. Since the Gerstner wave object is a uasset though I don't know how i can modify the file in order to expose the variables for the sequencer etc, is it even possible?

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can expose variables from a UAsset by creating a Blueprint based on the asset and then adding the variables as public or editable properties.

**Here are the steps to expose variables from a UAsset:**

1. Open the Editor and navigate to the Content Browser.
2. Find the UAsset that you want to expose variables from.
3. Right-click on the UAsset and select "Create Blueprint Class" from
   the context menu.
4. In the Blueprint editor, you should see the components or properties
   of the UAsset in the Components panel or Details panel.
5. To expose a variable, select the component or property that you want
   to expose and then click on the "Blueprint" button in the Details
   panel.
6. In the Blueprint section, you can set the variable to be public,
   protected, or private. If you want to be able to edit the variable
   in the editor, set it to "Editable".
7. Compile the Blueprint and save it.

*Once you have created the Blueprint, you can use it in your game or level and access the exposed variables as properties of the Blueprint instance.*

Comment: Thank you so much for the elaborate guide. Unfortunately it didn´t work in my case. The gerstner wave generator is not very straight forward and includes various elements, so that´s probably why. Thanks anyway!